# Are variables calculated first in Update?

Tags: sql-server, variables, sql-update

I have a query that seems to be calculating the variable before anything else. I created two temporary variables to track this and they are always equal even when I have one before and after the variable update:

```
DECLARE @swapTracker int
    SET @swapTracker = 0
DECLARE @currentStatus int
    SET @currentStatus = 0
update a
    set @swapTracker = (case
            when a.opt_out_ranking = 1
                then 0
            else (case 
            when a.do_not_email_ap = @currentStatus
                then @swapTracker
            else @swapTracker + 1
            end)
        end)
        ,a.swap_tracker = @swapTracker
        ,a.ap_var_test = @currentStatus
        -- Going to try to mark when someone Opted in
        ,opt_in_date = (case
            when opt_out_ranking = 1
                then (case 
                when a.do_not_email_ap = 0
                    then a.create_date
                else null
                end)
            else (case 
            when a.do_not_email_ap = @currentStatus
                then null
                else (case 
                when a.do_not_email_ap = 0
                    then a.create_date
                else null 
                end)
            end)
        end)
        -- Going to try to mark when someone Opted out
        ,opt_out_date = (case
            when opt_out_ranking = 1
                then (case 
                when a.do_not_email_ap = 1
                    then a.create_date
                else null
                end)
            else (case 
            when a.do_not_email_ap = a.ap_var_test
                then '2050-01-01 01:00:00.001'
                else (case 
                when a.do_not_email_ap = 1
                    then a.create_date
                else '2090-01-01 01:00:00.001'
                end)
            end)
        end)
        ,@currentStatus = (case
            when @currentStatus <> a.do_not_email_ap
                then a.do_not_email_ap
            else @currentStatus end)
        ,a.current_status = @currentStatus
FROM ##temp_email_opt_inout_date a
```

Is this by design or am I overlooking something? The @currentStatus variable IS changing so I know that's not where the issue lies, it just seems to be carrying this change into both the a.ap_var_test and a.current_status fields no matter where I put them in relation to @currentStatus.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, and the snippet unfortunately is a bit large for me to infer what section you're talking about. Can you just provide a bit more of a concise description of which variable you're having an issue with and what you *expect* to happen? It's also a bit strange to me that you're updating SQL params *in the middle* of a SQL update.

Comment: It seems like variables values are setting up first then update on table columns are done.

Comment: An update is a single piece of work. There is no concept of order of updates. This means that any columns or variables will have the value BEFORE the update statement for the ENTIRE statement. Values do not change in the middle, it wouldn't make sense if it did and you would break the ACID principles with that. Do be careful using global temp tables, they are highly prone to concurrency issues.